# How to load the local resource in chrome?

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, path, resources

I want to show the picture before it upload to the server.
But when I get the path of the picture and want to assign it to the image tag.
I found the error tips below in chrome.

> Not allowed to load local resource: xxxxxxxxx

Could you tell me how to resove this problem?

Comment: You're not allowed to do that.

Comment: This is why you should always have a development server, and never code live against production.

Comment: @SLaks if so.How to show the picture for user when they want to upload it ?Is it necessary to upload it to the server first ,then return a path to the client?